# CodeIgniter redirect from a view page to another view page

Tags: php, codeigniter, model-view-controller

I'm currently using CodeIgniter and trying to create two form.
One form for username/password which is already done. (So we assume that the user has an account).
One form for create an account.(Not finish yet).
I load the first link using my controller like

```
$this->load->view('Login_view');
```

The first problem I encountered is to find a way to load a view file from another view file ?
Once in my 'Login_view' file I tried this way for load another view file by this way:

```
<p><a href="<?php echo site_url('index.php/New_account.php')?>">New account</a></p>
```

or this way

```
    <p><a href="http://localhost:8888/CodeIgniter-3.0.0/index.php/New_account.php">New account</a></p>
```

and the last one

```
   <p><a href="<?php echo base_url('index.php/New_account.php')?>">New account</a></p>
```

Otherwise neither of those works. So is it possible to open another page from a view file or the only way is to get back into my controller class and open the desire view file ? Or perhaps is it the wrong way to do it ?

This is the beginning of my controller code (I suppose that the beginning is reasonable)

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Verifylogin extends CI_Controller {

 function __construct()
 {
   parent::__construct();
   $this->helper->helper('url');
   $this->load->model('user','',TRUE);
 }
```

Thanks

Comment: What is your controller name where you write the code to load view??

Comment: @Saty : Hello, I edited my message which contain now the beginning of my controller code :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply make registration function in controller and load view from it, like

```
  function registration()
  {
    $this->load->view('New_account');
  }
```

and in login view add link for registration

```
<a title="New account" href='<?php echo base_url ('controller_name/registration'); ?>'>New account</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Active record

```
 echo anchor('verifylogin/user', 'New account', 'title="New account"');
```

Make sure you upload

```
$this->load->helper('url');
```

**Controller**

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Verifylogin extends CI_Controller {

 function __construct()
 {
   parent::__construct();
   $this->helper->helper('url');
   $this->load->model('user','',TRUE);

 }
 function user()
 {
     $this->load->view('New_account');
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the redirect method in CodeIgniter to switch between the page views. Then for each page form add the `<?php echo site_url('controller_class/Controller_funtion');?>` . Then You have to make 2 controller functions,
1. For the `$this->load->view('Login');`
2. For the actions what should happen when the form is submitted.
As an example,

//For the login page load

```
function Login_load(){
      $this->load->view('login');
}

function LoginLoad(){
     if($this->input->post('submit')){
    //Things should happen when the form is submitted

}
}
```

When you need to change the view just type on the current function you're in,

```
redirect('Fuction_class/Login_Load', refresh);
```